# "unsupported type error" with RGBE loader for .HDR file types

Tags: vue.js, three.js, vite, hdr

I use ThreeJS, and specifically the RGBE loader to load my HDR files. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js

This worked fine until a recent upgrade, now when I attempt to use HDR files with the loader, I receive the following message:
When I try to run the code I receive an error at runtime: `THREE.RGBELoader: unsupported type:  1009`

[image]

It appears that the RGBELoader is unable to parse the file -- from googling this specific error, it seems to typically be due to people importing their HDR wrong.

For further reference, here is my asset-loading code:

```
// (prev code in my asset loader to get the path to the asset, and url of my .hdr file)

if (type == 'hdr') {
    new RGBELoader()
        .setDataType(THREE.UnsignedByteType)
        .setPath( _BASE_ASSET_URL )
        .load( url, function ( loadedItem ) {

            scope.assets[name] = loadedItem

    })
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> .setDataType(THREE.UnsignedByteType)

Since `r136`, the constant `THREE.UnsignedByteType` is not a valid data type for `THREE.RGBELoader` anymore. Please use `THREE.HalfFloatType` (the default)  or `THREE.FloatType`.

Comment: Ah thankyou! This was the solution

Comment: Would be great if you could accept this post as an answer then.